# websockets not working in virtual machine

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I am trying to work with websockets in linux virtual machine(with virtual box). Connection to  echo.websocket.org from HOST-OS works, but fails from Guest-OS.
My system config-:

Host-OS----windows 7

guest-Os----ubuntu 12.04

network config - NAT

Should I change the network configuration?

Comment: Change the network configuration to BRIDGED mode and see if it works for you.  This will place the ubuntu host on the same network as your windows host.

Comment: @Optichip thanks for replying. After changing NAT to BRIDGED ADAPTER, i can't open even google.com. In bridged configuration i have set adapter to Ethernet controller(only available option) and promiscuous mode to ALLOW VMs.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change your networking mode if you're just trying to access an external website like `webcoket.org`.  You said it fails, how does it fail?  Are you trying to access it from a browser?  Which browser? Which version? What error message do you get back?

Comment: @heavyd There is a test for websocket on www.websocket.org. It is failing that test.[link](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html). It says Error undefined. I'm working on firefox 25 which supports websocket.